# Multiline blocks in tag interpolation

Tags: pug

I'm using Pug templates to write articles in HTML and have run into issues with extremely long lines when interpolating tags into plain text. For example:

```
blockquote(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806776/').
  It is an ABI break for the operating system,
  but that is no big deal for OpenBSD.
  De Raadt #[a(href='https://lwn.net/Articles/806869/') said]:
  #[q(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806869/') we here at OpenBSD are the kings of ABI-instability].
  He #[a(href='https://lwn.net/Articles/806870/') suggested] that
  relying on the OpenBSD ABI is fraught with peril:
  #[blockquote(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806870/') Program to the API rather than the ABI. When we see benefits, we change the ABI more often than the API. I have altered the ABI. Pray I do not alter it further.]
```

Note the extremely long lines, especially the last block quote element at the end. It's really hard to read and overflows even on the largest of my displays. In the real source files this problem is even worse since it's several identation levels deep.

How do I break it up?

I tried the following:

```
#[blockquote(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806870/').
  Program to the API rather than the ABI.
  When we see benefits,
  we change the ABI more often than the API.
  I have altered the ABI.
  Pray I do not alter it further.]
```

However, that gives me the following error:

> End of line was reached with no closing bracket for interpolation.

Which suggests pug does not support parsing multiple lines during tag interpolation at all.

Is there a way to do this or should I make an issue about it on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use the [piped text syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text) instead of the block in a tag syntax.

```
blockquote(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806776/')
  | It is an ABI break for the operating system, 
  | but that is no big deal for OpenBSD. 
  | De Raadt #[a(href='https://lwn.net/Articles/806869/') said]: 
  q(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806869/') we here at OpenBSD are the kings of ABI-instability]. 
  | He #[a(href='https://lwn.net/Articles/806870/') suggested] that 
  | relying on the OpenBSD ABI is fraught with peril: 
  blockquote(cite='https://lwn.net/Articles/806870/') Program to the API rather than the ABI. When we see benefits, we change the ABI more often than the API. I have altered the ABI. Pray I do not alter it further.
```

Note that this isn't really best practice because you'll have to put a trailing space at the end of each line in order to preserve spaces between words when it compiles. Most code editors have a "soft wrap" option that will dynamically wrap lines in your code based on your window width (without actually inserting any line breaks).

Comment: I'm aware of pipe syntax but avoided it precisely because of the whitespace issues you mentioned.  Interleaving tags in-between pipes is also extremely ugly, inline tag interpolation is so much nicer. There's really no way to do it with tag interpolation? If not, I think I'll use literal HTML instead.

Comment: That's what the pipe syntax is for. You can still use inline tag interpolation on a piped line. But soft wrapping is the way to go.